# Get parameter from Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created a directive to listen to arrow up and down presses. But I want to extract the key that was pressed. Is there a way to pass it through the directive?

```
/**
 * Call a function when down and up arrow keys are pressed
 */
directives.directive('arrowKey', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function(event) {

            //Arrow down
            if(event.which === 40) {

                scope.$apply(function(){
                    scope.$eval(attrs.arrowKey);
                });

                event.preventDefault();

            //Arrow Up
            }else if (event.which === 38){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    scope.$eval(attrs.arrowKey);
                });

                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    };
});
```

HTML usage:

```
<input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search" class="searchBox" ng-model = "searchText" ng-change = "getAutoCompleteSuggestions(searchText)" ng-enter="getMore(searchText)" arrow-key="arrowPressed(arg)"/>
```

Comment: Why not use angular  ng-keypress?

Comment: Because I didn't know about it.... haha. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using [ng-keypress](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angKeypress).

```
<input id="search" type="text" ng-keypress='keypress($event)' />


/* ctrl */
$scope.keypress = function($event){
  //check event here. 
  if($event.keyCode == 38){

  }
}
```

Example fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/3xyr6/

Comment: @WilliamFalcon what version of angular(added a fiddle above) ?